# How do I configure Traefik with this?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I can't for the life of me figure out how this should be setup.

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` (heavily redacted)

```
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker
      - --api.insecure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      web:

  transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission
    container_name: transmission
    volumes:
      - # bla bla bla
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.transmission.rule=Host(`transmission.foo.lan`)
      - traefik.http.services.transmission.loadbalancer.server.port=9091
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/ahhdsa
      - PUID=1234
      - PGID=1234
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
    dns:
      # local dns
    networks:
      web:
      extravlan:
        ipv4_address: # local ip

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  extravlan:
    driver: macvlan
    # plus configuration for interface
```

I have DNS working, traefik & transmission are on the same machine. But I can't visit transmission.foo.lan from my laptop (no firewall rules blocking this either), it just times out.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `- "traefik.enable=true"` and `entrypoint` on the router label on the transmission container.

Try:

```
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker
      - --api.insecure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      web:

  transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission
    container_name: transmission
    volumes:
      - # bla bla bla
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.transmission.rule=Host(`transmission.foo.lan`)
      - traefik.http.services.transmission.loadbalancer.server.port=9091
      - traefik.http.routers.transmission.entrypoint=web
      # - traefik.docker.network=web
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/ahhdsa
      - PUID=1234
      - PGID=1234
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
    dns:
      # local dns
    networks:
      web:
      extravlan:
        ipv4_address: # local ip
```